# When is really useful to use a nested Java class?

Tags: java, class, nested

Could you give me a concrete example where a nested java class is useful?
I am studying it, I understand how it works but I can not imagine a real situation where its use is really necessary.

Thank you so much

Marco

Comment: When you need one. If you don't, there is no point for them.

Comment: if a Test requires a mocked/special implementation of a Class then you can nest it in the Test class because its not used anywhere else

Comment: Hey Marco, that is indeed an interesting question though it might be opinion based so there is no clear correct answer to it. A good example would be when you want to define a container class that is used exclusively by the wrapping class.

Comment: A nested enum in a class comes to mind as a pattern I use frequently. This allows you for example to have a class called `Process` with a nested enum called `Status`. In the process class, you can just refer to the enum as `Status`. From outside the `Process` class you refer to it as `Process.Status` which is very descriptive.

Comment: There are a lot of situations where nested classes are suitable. It is mainly a structural choice... internal implementations of a specific interface, internal state holding classes, even lambdas are equivalent of internal classes. Note that non-static classes see private members of the defining class.

Comment: Just look at the standard Java Collections. For example `HashMap` has several nested and inner classes for nodes, iterators, etc. They are all specific to the implementation of `HashMap`, so they benefit from being nested inside of that class.

Comment: Have a look on this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). There are three points mentioned why use nested classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most concise summary of when to use a nested class is: *when that class is logically part of the outer class' API, or when it encapsulates behavior specific to the outer class*.

For example, `Map.Entry`: it's an entry in a mapping. It's logically part of `Map`'s API, so it makes sense to put it inside `Map`.

Another common example is [Builder classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern): you use a `Builder` to make a thing, so it makes sense to put it inside that thing.

These are classes that you only really use in the context of using the outer classes: *sometimes* you might use a `Map.Entry` by itself as some sort of pair class; and sometimes you might want to use a `Builder` by itself, for example as a parameter to a method which puts things into that builder, but doesn't actually do the building itself. These cases are probably rarely far from code that also uses the outer class too: you're still using some aspect the outer class' API, so they do still logically belong to that API.

You could put such classes at the top level, alongside the "main" class. There are a few reasons why you might not want to do this:

- It clutters the namespace. If you've got classes `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz` etc, having `FooBuilder`, `BarBuilder`, `BazBuilder` at the top level just makes it harder to see the "useful" top level classes.

  - [Google's protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) generate a `Builder` class for every message type. Given the number of protocol buffers used in Google code, this clutter would be far too cumbersome.
- Nested classes have access to private fields of the outer class, which may help you do certain things without unnecessarily exposing those fields.
- You can refer to nested classes by qualifying the outer name, e.g. `Outer.Builder`, rather than having to explicitly `import some.pkg.OuterBuilder` *as well as* `import some.pkg.Outer`. Admittedly, I don't really care about the number of imports, since I just keep them collapsed in intellij.

You can also use them to encapsulate internal logic or intermediate state in the class: for example, I like to define private nested classes when I find myself passing around the same N parameters between private methods in a class. This is stuff that you don't want people outside your class to care about; it's merely convenient inside the class.

Comment: Thank you **very** much: you kindly answered and the information you give here is exactly what I was looking for, and I couldn't find by myself. Have a great day ! Thank

Answer (score 1):

It's used (also) to implement the [Builder Pattern](https://www.journaldev.com/1425/builder-design-pattern-in-java#builder-design-pattern-example-in-jdk)

> First of all you need to create a static nested class and then copy all the arguments from the outer class to the Builder class

Answer (score 0):

I found them useful when I have classes that are part of one another evolving together.
For instance, if I have base abstract classes:

```
abstract class Unit {
  private int HP;
  ....
  abstract class AI {
    abstract void heal();
  }
}
```

Later on, I can specify which type of unit I'm designing:

```
class Infantry extends Unit {
  ...
  class InfantryAI extends AI {
    void heal() { this->HP++; }
  }
}
```

What you see there is a *secondary `this`* - non-static nested classes (aka *inner classes* like `AI` and `InfantryAI`) can access their surrounding classes' (`Unit` and `Infantry`) private attributes as their own, and that access right propagates down the inheritance tree.

As for them being necessary - none of these OOP constructs are really necessary, but if it makes sense to you during design phase (like I thought it might be logical that `AI` is part of every `Unit` type so that it can control even it's private members), then you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

Nested classes are a way to organizing your code, one could say, sort of tight Encapsulation. While nested classes are not applicable to all situations, they are particularly useful when handling events.

The scope of a nested class is bounded by the scope of its enclosing class. So, if class B is defined within class A, then B does not exist independently of A. A nested class has access. to the members, including private members, of the class in which it is nested. However, the enclosing class does not have access to the members of the nested class. A nested class that is declared directly within its enclosing class scope is a member of its enclosing class.

The most used is the inner class. An inner class is a non-static nested class. It has access to all of the variables and methods of its outer class and may refer to them directly in the same way that other non-static members of the outer class do.

Finally there are anonymous inner classes, which are inner classes that don’t have a name.